# Global filter, column filter in tanstack table in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am learning and implementing tanstack-table in my vue3 project. However, I couldn't find much documentation or tutorials about global filters and column filters for vue. I have spent a lot of time researching and implementing but still have not found a solution.

```
const table = useVueTable({
    data: dataTable,
    columns: columnsTable,
    enableFilters: true,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    initialState: {
        pagination: {
            pageSize: 10
        }
    },
    state: {}
});
```

As a newbie in vue and require to use tanstack table, please help me

I have a search input and a dropdown. I want when I click the search button, I will perform a filter search in two assumed columns name - input and gender - dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it seems most of their documentation is centered around the React version, but looking at that has helped me figure out the Vue version. Their React [example is here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/tanstack/table/tree/main/examples/react/filters?embed=1&file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.tsx%3A1%2C1).

For Vue a global filter is pretty simple. In the table config add `globalFilter()` under `state` which returns the value to filter on. This global filter will affect all columns.

```js
const myGlobalFilter = ref("");

const table = useVueTable({
    data: myData,
    columns: myColumns,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    state: {
        get globalFilter(): {
            return myGlobalFilter.value;
        }
    }
});
```

For column filters you need to flesh that out in your columns definitions. Be sure to assign an `id` and a `filterFn` to those you want filtering for. The value of `filterFn` can be a string from [this list of their built-in functions](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/filters#filter-functions), or you can make your own FilterFn and use that instead (see the definition for that just below the built-in list). Then you'll need to feed the data for filtering into `columnFilters()`, similarly under `state`, as an array containing objects with a `value` and the `id` that matches the column. I've been creating that with a computed value.

```js
const filterFoo = ref("");
const filterBar = ref("");
const filtersComputed = computed(() => {
    const filters = [];
    if (filterFoo.value) filters.push({ id:"foo", value:filterFoo.value });
    if (filterBar.value) filters.push({ id:"bar", value:filterBar.value });
    return filters;
});

const myColumns = [{
    id: "foo",
    header: "Foo",
    accessorKey: "foo",
    filterFn: "includesString",
},{
    id: "bar",
    header: "Bar",
    accessorKey: "bar",
    filterFn: "equalsStringSensitive",
}];

const table = useVueTable({
    data: myData,
    columns: myColumns,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    state: {
        get columnFilters() {
            return filtersComputed.value;
        }
    }
});
```

It is possible to use both a global filter and column filters at the same time.